# Deleting two rows that have a same Value in a Parameter - SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table that contain similar Values in the Column  "Name" in different  rows, I would like to delete the duplicate ones and keep one, I tried the while loop but it didn't work, any simple methods to do that?

Comment: show your table schema, sample data, as well as SQL query. Thanks !

Comment: And also, which database are you using?  (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...)

Comment: This question has been answered many times in SO for lots of different database systems, this link should give you a start in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows Try searching for "delete duplicate sql" to get more examples.